# If product count reached, trigger alert. If product count already reached, don't trigger alert Woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce

I'm not sure if this is possible, or how to achieve this. I thought maybe a nested IF statement?

I am checking the product count in Woocommerce to check for a maximum of 4 items from a given category. I would like the IF statement to have logic as follows:

- If the count **becomes equal** to *4*, Trigger the javascript alert. *(i.e. from 3 to 4)*
- If the count **is already** *4*, do not trigger the javascript sweet alert if the user attempts to add another item to the cart. ***(This is where the js alert fires incorrectly)***
- If the count **becomes** *4 or more*, then **drops below** *4* and then **becomes equal** to *4* **again**, Trigger the javascript alert.

Currently whats happening is that the alert is triggering successfully for when 3 items becomes 4 items in the cart. But then it triggers the javascript alert again when the user attempts to add another and `added_to_cart` event fires.

```
                    success: function (response) {
                    $.each( JSON.parse(response), function( category, count ) {
                        if( count == 4 ){ //IF STATEMENT HERE                         
swal({
  type: 'success',
  title: "You've Added The 4 Minimum "+category+" Items!",
  allowOutsideClick: false,
  showCancelButton: false,
  showConfirmButton: false,
timer: 3000,
})        
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
if( count < 4 ){ alertQty=true;} 
if( count == 4 && alertQty=true ){ console.log("ALERT"); alertQty=false}
```

you use a second var to control the state alert

good luck